# MIT scheme draw-line

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

Has anyone been successful in getting draw-line working using MIT-scheme?

https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.4

Comment: there's a [racket package specifically designed for making the pictures from that chapter in SICP](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/soegaard/sicp.plt/2/1/planet-docs/sicp-manual/index.html). See my answer for more

Answer (score 5):

The key words are:

> For instance, suppose we have a procedure draw-line that draws a line on the screen between two specified points.

In other words, there **is no** `draw-line` -- it's purely hypothetical.

Comment: That's not true: the authors of the book actually implemented those procedures, and [it's listed on the official book page](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/psets/ps4hnd/readme.html).

Answer (score 2):

I used [`scmutils`](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/installation.html) provided by Gerald Sussman. It's a numerical and algebraic package used in his class on classical mechanics and has low-level support for [plotting graphs](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/users/gjs/6946/graphing.pdf).

Assuming you have defined `make-vect` and `make-seg`

```
(define line (make-seg (make-vect 2 3) (make-vect 4 1)))

(define win1 (frame -5 5 -5 5))

(define (draw-line frame a b)
  (plot-line frame (xcor a) (ycor a) (xcor b) (ycor b))
)
```

This is what I got after implementing the picture language

[image: george's square limit]

Answer (score 1):

There was an [actual MIT Scheme package](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/psets/ps4hnd/readme.html) made by the authors of the book for the picture language in that part of the book ([SICP section 2.2.4](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2.4)). However, the package was written in 1993 and I haven't had any luck getting it to work on my Mac OS High Sierra.

However, a much more recent package by someone else made specifically for that part of the book includes all functions, including draw-line, and you can actually make the pictures and play around with them. Download racket, and run the following:

```
(require (planet "sicp.ss" ("soegaard" "sicp.plt" 2 1)))
```

For more, see [the user manual for this very awesome package](http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/soegaard/sicp.plt/2/1/planet-docs/sicp-manual/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

When following this part of the book I decided to make `draw-line` generate JavaScript code that would draw on HTML canvas.

```
(define (draw-line v1 v2)
  (newline)
  (display "ctx.beginPath();")
  (display (string-append "ctx.moveTo(" (number->string (xcor-vect v1)) "," (number->string (ycor-vect v1)) ");"))
  (display (string-append "ctx.lineTo(" (number->string (xcor-vect v2)) "," (number->string (ycor-vect v2)) ");"))
  (display "ctx.stroke();"))
```

After all how exactly `draw-line` is implemented is not important for the procedures that use it and we just need a way to visualize the results. The only downside is that HTML canvas coordinates start in the top left corner, not in the left bottom, but that might also be dealt with by adjusting the code being generated a bit.

Here is the full Scheme code https://github.com/antivanov/scip-exercises/blob/master/scheme/ch2/2.48.49.scm https://github.com/antivanov/scip-exercises/blob/master/scheme/ch2/2.52.scm

Following the same approach I was able to visualize other examples/excercises from the chapter.

Answer (score -1):

I finished this painter assignment for one of my classes. For 2.47, you don't need to worry about draw-line really. All you need to do is make the constructors and selectors:

```
(define (make-frame origin edge1 edge2)
(list origin edge1 edge2))

(define (origin-frame frame)
(car frame))

(define (edge1-frame frame)
(cadr frame))

(define (edge2-frame frame)
(caddr frame))
```